# Running Git on multiple computers

Tags: git

I'm new to the whole concept of distributed version control systems and current I'm in the process of moving my open source projects to Github.

The question is this:

I have two computers that I usually work with targeting the same repository at GitHub.

Do those two machines have to be set up in a way so that git can distinguish the one from the other? Do I need two public keys or something?

Answer (score 3):

Git doesn’t need to distinguish anything. You might want to include both machines’ public keys in GitHub’s repository configuration so you can push and pull without a password. You also have to make sure your committer information (`user.name` and `user.email`, see `git config --help`) are set correctly on both machines. Apart from that you should be good to go.

Comment: The relevant public key is associated with a user, not a machine.  You can use the same one on both machines.

Comment: True. Normally you don’t copy the required secret keys to other machines, though. (At least I never use a secret key on more than one machine.)